# Why does photoluminescence of a semicon quantum well has only one peak?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory

When you grow a sandwich-structured semiconductor, like the one on the image below, you create a quantum well due to different materials having different bandgaps and band offsets. The energy difference between confinement levels of electrons and holes (green lines) is measured with photoluminescence setup.

[image]

The photoluminescence experiment just creates electron-hole pairs in the wafer, and then they travel in the material randomly (A on the image) and then they fall into the quantum well (B), and they stay at the confinement levels until they recombine (C).

Why does a quantum well spectrum have a peak that corresponds to C only, but there's never B-beak? What happens to the energy of carriers that fall into the well, before they recombine?

Comment: Because the electrons thermalize down to the band edge very quickly, much faster than the emission lifetime.

Comment: @JonCuster aren't you confusing band edges and confinement levels?